# Dynatree, parent node unchecked even all childs are checked

Tags: jquery, dynatree

I am using [Dynatree](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?SFoGTfLr) (Ver: 1.2.7) for creation of a hierarchical multi-selection. The **checkboxes and selectMode 3** option given in its site.

I have a parent child structure as below:

```
var treeData = [
{title: "TST", key: "TST" }, 
{title: "A1", key: "a1",expand: true,
  children: [
       {title: "A2", key: "a2" ,expand: true ,
       children: [
              {title: "A3", key: "a3" }
            ]
       }     
     ]
   },   
];
```

Basically:

```
A1
 |
 A2
  |
  A3
```

Now what i needed was that if i select **A1** all childs under it should get selected (i.e. checkboxes checked). This works fine.

But if i select on **A3** only **A3** should get selected. 
Here as **A3** is the only child of **A2**, and **A2** the only child of **A1**, so when i select **A3** all of them are getting selected. i.e even **A2** and **A1** are getting selected.

I understand that its a hierarchical structure so if i select all childs of a parent the parent itself gets selected.

But is there a parameter which changes thing the way am looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Was able to solve it.  Instead of **selectMode : 3** use **selectMode : 2**.

Then in **select** callback function iterate the children and select/unselect them based on parent as below.

```
select : function(event, data) {
    data.node.visit(function (childNode) {          
    childNode.setSelected(data.node.selected);
});
```